# Combine(Concatenate) two columns to third(PK) on insert query, sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I am using sql server 2014 for windows form application,I have columns like this

id | AccountNo | Location

COLUMN DETAILS:

id ---> int, not null, auto increment

AccountNo ---> varchar(50), not null, Primary Key

Location --->  varchar(50), not null

I am want to run sql INSERT query to enter user input so that it would be like this

| id     | AccountNo | Location|

| 10000  | PK10000   | PK      |

I am thinking the QUERY LIKE THIS

string strCommand ="INSERT INTO Customer(ID, AccountNo, Location) values (@ID, CONCAT(@Location, @ID [, @AccountNo]), @Location)";

Or is it possible to create an trigger which would combine two columns at insert if it is not possible this way as the AccountNo is PK

Suggestions please..

Comment: It seems that AccountNo is just a concatenation of the other two columns? You should look at computed columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really shouldn't concatenate like this for primary key values. For example, you could get duplicate values. It's better to create an IDENTITY column to be the primary key. If you really need the extra column for display purposes, then add a computed column. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Location VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    AccountNo AS CAST(ID AS VARCHAR) + Location
)
```

Now you only need to INSERT like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Location) VALUES ('PK')
```

This will give you a row with these values:

```
ID  Location AccountNo
1   PK       1PK
```

You could also create a constraint on the computed column to enforce unique values for AccountNo:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
    ADD CONSTRAINT UX_MyTable_AccountNo UNIQUE (AccountNo)
```

Comment: Thank you it seems working. As the table with columns was there I just updated the AccountNo as you said in the SSMS. I just changed the sequence of the statement to get AccountNo in 'PK10000' format.